# Improving performance (speed) of kNN classifier

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, knn

As an assignment I have to create my own kNN classifier, without the use of for loops. I've managed to use `scipy.spatial.KDTree` to find the nearest neighbour(s) of each vector in the testing set, and then I use `scipy.stats.mode` to return the list of the predicted classes. However, this takes extremely long when the size of the set is very large. For example, I have created the following example inspired by [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy import spatial
from scipy.stats import mode

def predict(X_test):
    X = Y_train[tree.query(X_test, k=k)[1]]
    Y = mode(X, axis=-1)[0].T[0]
    return Y

def load_data():
    x1 = 1.5 * np.random.randn(100) + 1
    y1 = 1.5 * np.random.randn(100) + 2
    x2 = 1.5 * np.random.randn(100) + 3
    y2 = 1.5 * np.random.randn(100) + 4
    X  = np.vstack((np.hstack((x1,x2)),np.hstack((y1,y2)))).T
    y  = 1.0*np.hstack((np.zeros(100), np.ones(100)))
    return X, y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, y = load_data()
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

    k = 7
    Z = predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
```

This takes very long (40-60 seconds!) because of the `X = Y_train[tree.query(X_test, k=k)[1]]` part. Is there any way I can improve the speed of *this* specific implementation, or should I think of another way to do it? For example, `sklearn`'s implementation only takes 0.4 seconds, which is insanely fast compared to my implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to read your a code a couple of times, but then I saw you're using `KDTree` and not `cKDTree`. The latter is implemented in Cython (instead of plain python and numpy) and should give you a decent speedup.